# How does one add RedCloth to a form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcloth

An embaressing question, but I can't seem to translate the documentation to an actual form_for. This is all the site provides..

```
RedCloth.new("Some text").to_html
 #=> "<p>Some text</p>"
```

I get that that's how I parse it after its been saved. But how do I save it as marked up text?

Here's my attempt at beginning this, but I don't know how to set the parameter to save the textarea as RedCloth. Any ideas?

```
- form_for @text do |f|
   # some RedCloth instantiation
   f.submit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't save the parameter parsed as RedCloth like that, nor would I recommend it. Parsing it into RedCloth will result in the original value being lost unless you stored the output in an alternate field, which is what I *would* recommend.

You can use a `before_save` in your model to parse that value and store it:

```
before_save :parse_text

# your model methods go here

private

  def parse_text
    self.parsed_text = RedCloth.new(text).to_html
  end
```

When you want to render the `parsed_text` value in your view you'll have to tell Rails that it's safe by doing this:

```
@object.parsed_text.html_safe
```

However, the code contained here does not account for people mixing Markdown and HTML, so be *very* careful how you use it.

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan Bigg. sorry for the belated response. Works like a charm!!

Comment: where does the text parameter that gets passed into `RedCloth.new(text)` come from? before_save doesn't pass anything to parse_text?

Comment: @Leahcim: That's just an attribute from your model.